# How to check if there are characters in a string?

Tags: python

I will rephrase my queston cause I wasn't really clear sorry.`[enter code here][1]`

Here is my code , before that I have a list called sentence that the user inputs with stuff he wants
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1v7I5.png

The thing is that the variable mySentence still contains , , , if you enter , , , , , , in it. I don't understand why.

Sorry I wasn't clear enough

Comment: did you mean it will return 'good' for letters only?

Comment: Yes I want only letters from the latin alphabet, no punctuation or whitespaces, thank you.

Comment: But `isalnum()` returns `False` on a `","` string

Comment: Please add code and input data as text, not as an image, and format it properly. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

With regexp maybe :

```
import re
strg = "0129872198a28379"
reg = re.compile("[A-Za-z]+")
test = reg.match(strg)
```

Answer (score -2):

One possible solution might be:

```
def contains_char(str)
    for c in str:
        if ord(c.lower()) >= 97 and ord(c.lower()) <= 122:
            return True
    return False
```

The function is checking whether the ASCII value of the character is between that for letters of the English alphabet (`ord()` returns the ASCII value).

Comment: I didn't dv, but this only works on strings of length 1 (also it's normally bad practise to assign a lambda function, just write a regular function)

Comment: Oh, I did not realize that the function should have been for an entire string. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: No problem, but to be fair, i can't really clarify what the original OP meant- the question itself is unclear (and will likely be closed)